# mkl_blas_dgemm_alloc not found in mkl_intel_thread

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, virtualenv, intel-mkl

I developed a a [tool](https://github.com/Bloodmallet/bloodystats/tree/dev) in python 3.5 some time ago which currently only uses differential evolution from scipy to do its task. For some reasons I had to change settings on my machine and switch to use python in a virtual environment.

My specs now:

- win 10 64 bit
- used pip 9.0.1
- numpy 1.12.1+mkl
- scipy 0.19.0
- python 3.6.1

I have a different env using python 2.7 flying around somewhere else.

Now my problem....everytime the differential evolution function gets its first set of data it crashes after returning the differential_evolution step value.

The differential_evolution call can be found under ./libraries/methods/differential_evoluation.py line 76

The pop-up Error is "Entry point '`mkl_blas_dgemm_alloc wasn't found in 'mkl_intel_thread.dll'.`" And the printed error is "`Intel MKL FATAL ERROR: Cannot load mkl_intel_thread.dll.`" Please notice that my system language is german therfore the pop-up message was translated by me.

I don't know whether this is relevant but my directory structure is:
>some_place/location1/goal.py
>some_place/location2/env/

I didn't work with virtualenv before and in addition to this i used python 3.5. I'd appreciate any help or instructions on how to add more information to this case to help clarify my problem.

Yours sincerely

Answer (score 0):

OK I'm back with more information. Maybe someone else will stumble uppon it. To be clear: I do not know the fix or reason. I just tried a bunch of stuff.

Using

> python 3.5.3,
> numpy 1.11.1+mkl and 
> scipy-0.18.0 or scipy-0.19.0

made the error disappear. I couldn't try numpy 1.11.1 or 1.11.2 for python 3.6 because [this kind soul](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy) sadly doesn't offer those versions anymore. I found the 1.11.1 version for python 3.5 somewhere on my disk.

From my testing i can tell that it breaks once i use `numpy 1.11.3` or higher. 1.11.1 works fine. Therefore I assume that some changes happened either in numpy between 1.11.1 and 1.11.3 which break it OR in how this kind soul creates/builds his wheels. So I'm going to use python 3.5 for now as i do not have numpy 1.11.1+mkl for python 3.6.

Yours sincerely